# Objective-C property infinite loop

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm currently learning Objective-C and it's also my first foray into programming so please bear with me.

I have a simple object called XYZPerson that holds a person's first name, last name and a reference to his or her partner. The partner also being an XYZPerson object.

Here's what I declared in the XYZPerson's header :

```
@interface XYZPerson : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *firstName;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *lastName;
@property (nonatomic, weak) XYZPerson *partner;

@end
```

and in the implementation I wrote this:

```
- (void)setPartner:(XYZPerson *)aPartner
{
    _partner = aPartner;
    aPartner.partner = self;
}
```

but in main(), whenever I call `personMale.partner = personFemale;` it creates an infinite loop.

I think I understand why (because aPartner.partner calls setPartner which calls itself and again), but I can't find an elegant solution to correct this problem.

Any help — with explanations of how it works — would be much appreciated!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should not be using Objective-C for your "first foray into programming".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that this line:

```
aPartner.partner = self;
```

does something you didn't realize it would do: it is merely a shorthand for calling `setPartner:`. Setting a property calls the corresponding setter method; that in fact is all a property really is, i.e. a way of calling a setter/getter method!

But that line is *in* the implementation of `setPartner:`. So you are now in an infinite recursion: you are calling yourself. It is *exactly* as if you said:

```
- (void)setPartner:(XYZPerson *)aPartner
{
    _partner = aPartner;
    [aPartner setPartner: self];
}
```

which, since these are all XYZPersons, is *obviously* a recursion.

After all, you would never say this:

```
- (void)setPartner:(XYZPerson *)aPartner
{
    [self setPartner: = aPartner];
}
```

But that in fact is just the kind of thing you *are* saying!

When you are in a setter, for this very reason, you must never *call* the setter; you should refer only to the underlying instance variable:

```
- (void)setPartner:(XYZPerson *)aPartner
{
    self->_partner = aPartner;
    aPartner->_partner = self;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your setter, only make the assignment if the partner is changing:

```
- (void)setPartner:(XYZPerson *)aPartner
{
    if(_partner != aPartner) {
        _partner = aPartner;
        aPartner.partner = self;
    }
}
```

Another solution would be to create a separate method to make two people partners.

```
- (void)makePartner:(XYZPerson *)aPartner {
        self.partner = aPartner;
        aPartner.partner = self;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Think about what happens when you invoke setPartner on an XYZPerson.

Let's say you say

```
XYZPerson *a = [[XYZPerson alloc] init];
XYZPerson *b = [[XYZPerson alloc] init];

a.partner=b;
```

In person a's setPartner method, it sets it's partner property to the other person (b), then invokes person b's setPartner method..

Ok, now person b's setPartner method fires. In that method, it sets it's own partner property, then says tells it's new partner (person a) to set its partner property to self (person b), which invokes the person a's setPartner method again, and so on, ad infinitum. (forever.)

You could break the loop with an if statement:

```
- (void)setPartner:(XYZPerson *)aPartner
{
    if (_partner != aPartner)
    {
        _partner = aPartner;
        aPartner.partner = self;
    }
}
```

Now, with the modified code, the sequence would be:

```
a.partner = b;
```

person's a's partner property is nil, so it sets it to b, then invokes b's setPartner method.

In person b's setPartner method, it's partner is also nil, so person b sets it's partner property to person a, then invoke's person a's setPartner method again.

However, this time person a's partner property already points to person b, so the if statement evaluates as false and the method does nothing.